# Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, iife

Here's the code, it's pretty simple:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  // Define our constructor
  this.White = function() {
    this.version = "1.0.0";
  };
}());

// Later
a = new White();
alert(a.version);
```

<strike>In [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dapokufudo/1/) (and when running JShint), it works like it should.</strike> Doesn't work in JSBin after adding `"use strict"`. When running this script in Chrome, however, I get this vague message:

[image]

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'White' of undefined

### Why?!

Comment: Because of `use strict` `this` is `undefined`, othrwise it'd be the global object.

Comment: Your code is expecting `this` to be a reference to the global object. In your code (outside jsbin), if the outer scope is in "strict" mode, then `this` will be `undefined` (because that's how "strict" mode works).

Comment: @elclanrs thanks, that does make sense! So I just need to do `window.White` instead of `this.White` correct?

Comment: Note that the JSBin appears to have been saved without the `"use strict";` in the snippet you posted.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski my bad, thanks for pointing that out. Adding `'use strict';` to JSBin breaks it too .. updating the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using strict mode will not let you create implicit globals.this.White is hoisted globally and it is implicitly created.So removing it will remove the error [Strict Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Comment: If you'd rather not disabled strict mode, you can simple replace `this.White = ...` with `window.White = ...`, for browser based JS.